# Who is the father of Minato Namikaze?

Tags: naruto

Does Namikaze mean a clan or is it just his second name?

I think the only way [Naruto](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki) could defeat [Madara Uchiha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha) is to be in a blood-line relation with the [Sage of the Six Paths](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hagoromo_%C5%8Ctsutsuki), and thereby achieving a [Rinnegan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rinnegan) of his own.

Since [Kushina](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kushina_Uzumaki), Mother of Naruto is from [Uzumaki clan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Uzumaki_clan); which is a blood-relative of the [Senju clan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Senju_clan), it will make sense if [Minato](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Minato_Namikaze) is from any distant clan related to [Uchiha clan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Senju_clan).

Is there any clue revealing who might be the parents of Minato?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there are no clues, at least not yet (in the anime).

But your second part of question/theory is obviously incorrect, since it's not enough to be related to an Uchiha, because it's not the DNA you need (directly, as is the case with the Senju part), but rather it's the eye itself. Since Naruto doesn't have a Sharingan, even if he's related to the Senju (distantly), he wouldn't be able to awaken the Rinnegan - not even if, by some miracle, Minato were to be related to the Uchihas (it seems pretty impossible to me). So, if Naruto were to not get a Sharingan, e.g. from Sasuke, in my opinion, he will never be able to awaken the Rinnegan.

As with the fight, I've no idea about the manga; the only thing I know is that he will team up with Sasuke (from older posts, which made me crazy...), but off-topic, I think there is more in Naruto, even without a Rinnegan, which could equal AND overpower Madara.

Related to your question, we don't know anything about Minato's parents. "Namikaze" could represent his association with a clan (as in most of the cases), or it could simply be his second name.

Answer (score 2):

Woah woah woah woah woah.... Naruto will never achieve Rinnegan.... [**Rinnegan**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/3187/rinneg4n) has given a proper explanation for it.

To put your answer short:

1. No information about Minato's parents has been revealed. It isn't important, anyway.
2. "Namikaze" *could be a clan* [don't know if it falls in Senju clan]. But it is definitely not associated with Uchiha since all members of the Uchiha clan had the "Uchiha" name. (most common observation has been taken into consideration here.)
3. The Uzumaki clan were the only ones who were associated with Minato for a while. First, it was his wife, Kushina, who belonged to the Uzumaki clan. Secondly, he learned many sealing techniques from the Uzumaki clan.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the existing answers. I do have a theory that the 4 Hokages' father, Minato Namikaze's father is the Second Hokage.

I also thought the same thing about what actually happened. He had an off relationship with a woman with the last name of Namikaze. Now, one of these three possibilities could happen and I know it's kind of unusual:

- He died before he can be told about the baby, so she put the child up for adoption, or
- She put a child up for adoption before he died, possibly to keep it send me from getting to it, or
- She died in childbirth.

It would be interesting if we could get the creator of one of those opinions on this.

Comment: If Minato was Tobirama's son, it would mean he is maybe 15 years younger than Hiruzen. Minato was Hiruzen's student's student. Minato was probably not even alive till Hiruzen was like 35 years old. I don't know where you got this theory, but this is worse than scientology